# Как сделать подобную html разметку?

Tags: html, вёрстка, responsive

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Левая панель с фиксированной шириной, высота - на всю высоту страницы, между шапкой и футером.

*Средний блок без фиксированной ширины и высоты, резиновый.

*Правый блок фиксированный по высоте и ширине.

*Header имеет position:fixed;

*Footer должен быть прижат к низу экрана, а основной блок растянут на всю высоту.

Проблема с центральным блоком, если ему не задать ширину, то получается как-то так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код:

```css
/*CSS Base =================================*/
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a, img, ol, ul, li, form {margin:0; padding:0; border:0; font-size:100%; vertical-align:baseline;}

body {color:#111; font-family: "Tahoma", sans-serif;}
input, textarea {outline:none;}
h1 {font-size:36px; font-weight: normal;}
h2 {font-size:28px; font-weight: normal;}


p {font-size:18px; line-height:20px; }
a {outline:none; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {text-decoration: none;}
img {border:none; outline:0;}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
  zoom: 1;
}


/* HEADER */
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #ECECEC;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

/* MAIN CONTENT */
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
#container .left-panel {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #CACACA;
  float: left;
}
#container .content {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
#container .content .right-panel {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #CACACA;
}

/* FOOTER */
footer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ECECEC;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>HEADER</h1>
</header>

<section id="container" class="clearfix">
  <div class="left-panel">
    <h2>left-panel</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="right-panel">
      <h2>right-panel</h2>
    </div>
    <h2>main content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati illum ullam incidunt ducimus! Iusto ullam maxime aperiam laboriosam cupiditate nesciunt magnam dolores quas maiores accusamus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati illum ullam incidunt ducimus! Iusto ullam maxime aperiam laboriosam cupiditate nesciunt magnam dolores quas maiores accusamus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati illum ullam incidunt ducimus! Iusto ullam maxime aperiam laboriosam cupiditate nesciunt magnam dolores quas maiores accusamus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati illum ullam incidunt ducimus! Iusto ullam maxime aperiam laboriosam cupiditate nesciunt magnam dolores quas maiores accusamus.</p>


  </div>
</section>

<footer>
  <h2>footer</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore dolores enim pariatur amet velit magni numquam tempore ipsam, aut dolorum impedit laborum, corporis, explicabo placeat.</p>
</footer>
```

Еще попробовал вот так:

```css
/* MAIN CONTENT */
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 80px;
  min-width: 980px;
  display: table;
}
#container .left-panel {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #CACACA;
  display: table-cell;
}
#container .content {
  display: table-cell;
}
#container .content .right-panel {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #CACACA;
}
```

результат [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почти то, что надо, но теперь главный #container не растягивается на всю высоту страницы.

Comment: Зачем ты тратишь время на создание своей сетки ? Возьми готовую сетку bootstrap и посмотри как там реализована система колонок и сделай так же, а лучше переверстай сразу на сетке bootstrap

Comment: Мне в целях самообучения надо бы сперва самому разобраться, а не брать готовое решение.

Answer (score 1):

**Первое, что я заметил:**

У вас у `.left-column` стоит

```
height: 100%
```

Данное свойство не будет работать, если у его родителя не будет задана какая-то определенная высота(такое ограничение). Хорошо, смотрим на родителя...

Для `section#container` у вас тоже задана высота `height: 100%`. Что не так?
А `section#container` в свою очередь тоже смотрит на своего родителя, а в родителях у него `html` и `body`, а вот для них у вас не стоит высота `100%`, поэтому вся конструкция не растянется на всю высоту.

Поэтому задайте:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Второе:**

Вы используете свойство

```
#container .content {
    float: right;
}
```

Для основного контейнера, которое определяет высоту всего документа оно не нужно, поэтому уберите его, и задайте `margin-left: ширина левого блока`

**И еще:**
Исключите идентификаторы (#) из css правил, пользуйтесь только классами.

---

```css
/*CSS Base =================================*/
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a, img, ol, ul, li, form {margin:0; padding:0; border:0; font-size:100%; vertical-align:baseline;}
html, body{height: 100%}
body {color:#111; font-family: "Tahoma", sans-serif;}
input, textarea {outline:none;}
h1 {font-size:36px; font-weight: normal;}
h2 {font-size:28px; font-weight: normal;}


p {font-size:18px; line-height:20px; }
a {outline:none; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {text-decoration: none;}
img {border:none; outline:0;}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
  zoom: 1;
}


/* HEADER */
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #ECECEC;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

/* MAIN CONTENT */
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
#container .left-panel {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #CACACA;
  float: left;
}
#container .content {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 400px;
}
#container .content .right-panel {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #CACACA;
}

/* FOOTER */
footer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ECECEC;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>HEADER</h1>
</header>

<section id="container" class="clearfix">
  <div class="left-panel">
    <h2>left-panel</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="right-panel">
      <h2>right-panel</h2>
    </div>
    <h2>main content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati illum ullam incidunt ducimus! Iusto ullam maxime aperiam laboriosam cupiditate nesciunt magnam dolores quas maiores accusamus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati illum ullam incidunt ducimus! Iusto ullam maxime aperiam laboriosam cupiditate nesciunt magnam dolores quas maiores accusamus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati illum ullam incidunt ducimus! Iusto ullam maxime aperiam laboriosam cupiditate nesciunt magnam dolores quas maiores accusamus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati illum ullam incidunt ducimus! Iusto ullam maxime aperiam laboriosam cupiditate nesciunt magnam dolores quas maiores accusamus.</p>


  </div>
</section>

<footer>
  <h2>footer</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore dolores enim pariatur amet velit magni numquam tempore ipsam, aut dolorum impedit laborum, corporis, explicabo placeat.</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но вот теперь что делать с футером? Появился ненужный скролл

Comment: @Александр Лазневой Задайте высоту левой колонке "height: 80%",а футеру 20%, ибо сейчас левая колонка имеет 100% высоты.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```css
html,
body,
header,
footer,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
div,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  background: #004d80;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
footer {
  height: 120px;
  background: #004d80;
  margin-top: -120px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.left-panel {
  width: 200px;
  background: #669999;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
}
.main_content {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}
.content {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 120px;
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 120px;
}
.right-panel {
  background: #5c8a8a;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
.left-panel_block {
  margin-top: 100px;
  background: #5c8a8a;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>HEADER</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="main_content">

    <div class="left-panel">
      <div class="left-panel_block">
        <h2>left-panel</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">

      <div class="right-panel">
        <h2>right-panel</h2>
      </div>

      <h2>main content</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati illum ullam incidunt ducimus! Iusto ullam maxime aperiam laboriosam cupiditate nesciunt magnam dolores quas maiores accusamus.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati illum ullam incidunt ducimus! Iusto ullam maxime aperiam laboriosam cupiditate nesciunt magnam dolores quas maiores accusamus.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati illum ullam incidunt ducimus! Iusto ullam maxime aperiam laboriosam cupiditate nesciunt magnam dolores quas maiores accusamus.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati illum ullam incidunt ducimus! Iusto ullam maxime aperiam laboriosam cupiditate nesciunt magnam dolores quas maiores accusamus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
  <h2>FOOTER</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore dolores enim pariatur amet velit magni numquam tempore ipsam, aut dolorum impedit laborum, corporis, explicabo placeat.</p>
</footer>
```